# how to group by dataframe by date, by category and count the number of items per each category?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

need help with dataframe group by function.
I need to group by data of initial dataframe by date, by category and count the number of items per each category
stack with using `[pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='check_date')]`

Result dataframe is that what should be created

initial dataframe

```
check_date  category
1/20/2021   apple
1/19/2021   orrange
1/6/2021    orrange
1/6/2021    apple
2/11/2021   cherry
3/20/2021   apple
3/19/2021   apple
4/12/2021   Mango
4/15/2021   Mango
4/13/2021   Mango
5/28/2021   Mango
5/25/2021   orrange
```

Result dataframe:

```
check_date apple orrange cherry
1/31/2021  2       2      0
2/28/2021  0       0      1                 
3/31/2021  2       0      0
4/30/2021  4       0      0
5/31/2021  0       1      0
```

Comment: I t seems You forgot to ask a question

Comment: @Neither The question is in the header.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes Something based on "I have this, I want this, do it for me" is never a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['check_date'])
df = df.drop(['check_date'], axis = 1)

df = df.pivot_table(index=['Date'], columns='category', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
category    Mango  apple  cherry  orrange
Date                                     
2021-01-31      0      2       0        2
2021-02-28      0      0       1        0
2021-03-31      0      2       0        0
2021-04-30      3      0       0        0
2021-05-31      1      0       0        1
```